# Getting a Symbol not found error while importing a python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, qiskit

I'm trying to import a python module called qiskit, but whenever I do, I get the following error:

```
    ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _aligned_alloc
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

This occurred yesterday when I installed another module called ibm_quantum_widgets. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling qiskit but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?